# c++, declarar un struct como variable global

Tags: c++, struct

C++, al declarar un struct como variable global, mas adelante no puedo accederla desde un objeto (class)... El entorno de desarrollo está formado por tres ficheros:

- el 1er fichero contiene el pgm principal, asíestá definida la variable:

  ```
  struct  stXXX {
      TIMESTAMP_STRUCT  timestamp; // Horario de generación del registro en tabla VarProceso
      double            contador;  // Cantidad de bolas ingresadas
      float             diametro;  // Diametro de bolas ingresadas
  } stXXX;
  ```
- el 2do fichero es un header para la declaración de la clase.
- el 3er fichero contiene el código (c++) del objeto que es invocado desde el 1er fichero.

La struct está declarada antes del `main()` en el 1er fichero, si la uso en el pgm principal, no me genera ningún error.

El compilador me avisa que el `"identifier stXXX is undefined"` cuando la uso en el 3er fichero.

El proyecto lo manejo con Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015.

Mis preguntas son:

- a.- ¿Se puede hacer lo que estoy haciendo?
- b.- ¿Cómo debo declararla para que sea visible desde el código donde está programado el objeto (3er fichero)? o
- c.- ¿Cómo la referencio desde el 3er fichero?

Comment: ¿El primer fichero es un archivo de cabecera (`h` o `hpp`)? ¿Puedes mostrar tu `main.cpp`?

Comment: El primer fichero es un archivo .cpp.

Comment: Aquí va el código:

Comment: le quité los include, /*  @file Jc.cpp */
struct  stVarProceso {
 TIMESTAMP_STRUCT timestamp; 
 double  contador; 
 float diametro; 
} stVarProceso;
using namespace std;

int main() {

 int iTest = 0;
 struct stVarProceso stVarProceso1;
 string strVarProceso("SELECT");
 string strResultadoPH("INSERT ");
 // Se inicializa conexión a la BD
 SqlServerConnector connector = SqlServerConnector(Address, Db, User,Passw);
 stVarProceso1.timestamp.day = 10;
 stVarProceso.timestamp.day = 15;
connector.executeQueryVarProceso(_strdup(strVarProceso.c_str()));
  return 0;
} // fin jc.cpp

Comment: Esto es terrible **no uses los comentarios para añadir código, edita tu pregunta** lo que has publicado en los comentarios es ilegible, incomprensible e inútil, edita la pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema está claramente señalado en el error que recibes:

> `"identifier stXXX is undefined"`

Lo traduzco:

> `"el identificador stXXX no está definido"`

---

En C++ los archivos de código (normalmente con extensión `cpp`) alcanzan a ver todas las definiciones que estén contenidas en el mismo archivo o aquellas que hayan sido añadidas mediante una inclusión (`#include`), estos archivos de código se conocen también como ["Unidades de Traducción" [image]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)) (UdT).

Las definiciones de una UdT no son visibles en otras UdT, así que si tu estructura `stXXX` está en `"1er_fichero.cpp"` y la usas en `"3er_fichero.cpp"`, la UdT de *3er_fichero* no sabrá de la existencia de lo definido en la UdT de *1er_fichero* y en consecuencia se quejará de que "*el identificador stXXX no está definido*".

---

> ¿Se puede hacer lo que estoy haciendo?

Como puedes ver por el error de compilación: No.

> ¿Cómo debo declararla para que sea visible desde el código donde está programado el objeto (3er fichero)?

En `3er_fichero.cpp` debes incluir el archivo en que se define `stXXX`, que si no me equivoco es `2do_fichero.hpp`:

```
#include "2do_fichero.hpp"

int main()
{
    // ... hacer cosas ...
    return 0;
 }
```

> ¿Cómo la referencio desde el 3er fichero?

Una vez añadida la inclusión, puedes crear instancias del objeto `stXXX` con normalidad.